# How to build a parser to parse lucene syntax to an AST

Tags: parsing, lucene, abstract-syntax-tree

I have a requirement but I don't know much about implementation detail.
I have a query string like -->

```
(title:java or author:john) and date:[20110303 TO 20110308]
```

basically the query string is composed with lucene syntax.
What I really need to do is parse query string into AST and convert AST to lucene query.

I'm not familiar with compiler or parser technology and I ran into Irony project.
Can someone point me how to and where to start? Using Irony or hand-made will be okay.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

If your query String is in Lucene syntax, then simply pass it to the parse(String) method of Lucene's [QueryParser](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_2/api/core/org/apache/lucene/queryParser/QueryParser.html#parse(java.lang.String)).

That will return a Query object representing the query String.

If you need to extend or modify the standard lucene syntax, then you could start by looking at the [JavaCC Grammar for QueryParser](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/master/lucene/queryparser/src/java/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/QueryParser.jj).

Others have modified it in the past to [add support for RegExps](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-2039)

Comment: I know lucene's QueryParser. I actually want to design my own syntax but the syntax is pretty much same with lucene's query syntax. Not 100% same as lucene's syntax. So I need to know how to start or borrow from any exist open source project' ideas( implementation ) to accompolished it.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry for the late response:

Generally speaking, to create a parser, it's best to describe the grammar in the abstract, then generate the parser using a parser generator.

I created the [lucene-query-parser.js](https://github.com/thoward/lucene-query-parser.js) library using a [PEG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing_expression_grammar) grammar, which is in the Github repo [here](https://github.com/thoward/lucene-query-parser.js/blob/master/lucene-query.grammar). That grammar is specific to [PEG.js](http://pegjs.majda.cz/) and uses JavaScript to implement an AST style result for the parsed query.

It's not necessary to return an AST style structure, but I found that to be most useful for the project that I wrote the syntax for. You could re-implement the grammar to return any sort of parser result that you wanted to.

Answer (score 0):

You could also look at the [Myna parser](https://github.com/cdiggins/myna-parser) which is a JavaScript parsing library that has a sample [Lucene grammar](https://github.com/cdiggins/myna-parser/blob/master/grammars/grammar_lucene.js). The Myna parser automatically generates an AST that you can easily transform into whatever form you want.